# Cannot resolve symbol 'CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

I have this code that I would like to migrate to the latest version of `'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:3.1.1'`

```
import feign.Client;
import feign.httpclient.ApacheHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.SpringClientFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class LoadbalancerConfig {

  @Bean
  public Client client(
      HttpClientConnectionManager httpClientConnectionManager,
      CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory lbClientFactory,
      SpringClientFactory clientFactory) {

    CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(httpClientConnectionManager)
        .build();
    ApacheHttpClient client = new ApacheHttpClient(closeableHttpClient);
    return new LoadBalancerFeignClient(client, lbClientFactory, clientFactory);
  }
}
```

With version `'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-core:2.2.2.RELEASE'` the code is working fine bur when I switch to version 3.1.1 I get import errors:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'ribbon'
```

Do you know how I have to migrate the code?

Code example: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Generic_SO_POC/blob/master/src/main/java/org/merchant/database/service/sql/LoadbalancerConfig.java

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#known-issues ribbon was removed in 3.0.1 release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching more about... I found an issue in this [topic](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-cloud/issues/312):

> spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon has been removed from SpringCloud with [this version](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes)

Then you need to add the `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` dependency to your project.

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer:3.1.1'
```

Spring Cloud OpenFeign [official reference](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-openfeign/2.2.0.RC2/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults) in `1.2 Overriding Feign Defaults` section:

> **Client feignClient:** if Ribbon is in the classpath and is enabled it is a **LoadBalancerFeignClient**,
>
> otherwise if Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is in the classpath,
> **FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient** is used.
>
> If none of them is in the classpath, the default feign client is used.

So you can try to use the `FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient` in the `LoadBalancerConfig`:

```
import feign.Client;
import feign.httpclient.ApacheHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.support.LoadBalancerClientFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class LoadBalancerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Client client(HttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager,
                         LoadBalancerClient lbClient,
                         LoadBalancerClientFactory lbClientFactory) {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                    .build();
        ApacheHttpClient client = new ApacheHttpClient(httpClient);
        return new FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient(client, lbClient, lbClientFactory);
    }
}
```

---

##### References:

- [NoClassDefFoundError: springframework/cloud/openfeign/ribbon/LoadBalancerFeignClient](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-cloud/issues/312)
- [Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes)
- [Spring Cloud OpenFeign (1.2. Overriding Feign Defaults)](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-openfeign/2.2.0.RC2/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults)
- [NetFlix Ribbon GitHub](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon)

Comment: Thanks but how I need to update the Java code? I think that the issue here is code deprecation?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Sorry, I was thinked it's a dependency issue, but I updated the answer, look if helped you. Thanks!